# How to launch an app without any activity and a service need to run on launch

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I want to write app, without any activity (including activity_main) and need to run a service when app is launched.

Comment: Use BroadCastReceiver to run your service by adding BOOT_COMPLETED action.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Use @android:style/Theme.NoDisplay in manifest

Answer (score 0):

You can start the service from your activity onCreate, and then finish it.